# Relation between TQFT representations and factorizable sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, quantum-groups, mapping-class-groups, topological-quantum-field-theory

I am interested in the comparison between two different constructions which, as far as I can tell, are both supposed to produce rigorous constructions of Wess–Zumino-Witten conformal blocks.

More precisely, on the one hand, we have the construction of Reshetikhin–Turaev as well as Blanchet–Habegger–Masbaum–Vogel of "quantum representations" of mapping class groups of Riemann surfaces (possibly with marked points): see e.g. Section 3 of [Masbaum - Quantum representations of mapping class groups](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Egregor.masbaum/Masbaum.pdf) for a nice survey. On the other hand, the book of Bezrukavnikov–Finkelberg–Schechtman (BFS) [Factorizable sheaves and quantum groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9712001) produces  sheaves over certain stacks $\mathcal{M}_{A, \delta}$, which are, roughly, (a line bundle over) moduli stacks of curves with marked points **and** non-zero tangent vectors at these marked points; see for example Section 1.5 on page 9.

Question: how are these two constructions related?

I believe that they should be closely related, and this is perhaps well known to experts. I am confused by the appearance of tangent vectors in the moduli stacks $\mathcal{M}_{A, \delta}$ above, though I have perhaps misunderstood what are supposed to be the conformal blocks in BFS. Any comments or references would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The tangent vectors are also present in the RT construction, and in fact also in the WZW model even if it's sometimes swept under the rug. See e.g. https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~kirillov/tensor/tensor.html where this is done carefully in both settings (although they only treat the genus 0 part of WZW). Basically you need those for gluing to be well-defined.

Comment: Then yes, those constructions are equivalent basically because these produce modular functors attaching the same modular category to the circle.

Comment: @Adrien Thanks for the reference! Can you say more precisely how the two constructions are the same? For example, due to the tangent vectors, the BFS construction (as well as the manuscript you linked) seems to give sheaves over some torus bundle over M_{g,n}, so how does one obtain representations of mapping class groups?

Comment: What you get are representations of framed versions of mapping class groups, ie diffeomorphisms fixing the marked points and their tangent vectors modulo isotopies of those. If you cut out a disc around each marked point, this is the same as the version of the mapping class group of the obtained surface fixing the boundary pointwise (this is in fact a bit more complicated, even if there are no marked points for various reasons you only get representations of certain central extensions of mapping class groups).

Comment: Beware that in the Kauffmann bracket approach (which corresponds to the quantum group of $sl_2$) you can get rid of those tangent vectors, but this is kinda special and not very canonical.

Comment: Can you say a bit more the quantum $sl_2$ case and why the tangent vectors can be gotten rid of? Looking quickly at Blanchet–Habegger–Masbaum–Vogel I am guessing this has to do with the framing anomaly? For example, is it true that in the $sl_2$ case, one a priori gets representations of the framed MCG, but which turns out to actually come from (?) representations of the ordinary MCG? (I am also ignoring the issue of the central extension of MCG, which has to do with the determinant line bundle over $\mathcal{M_{g,n}$}$ and is, I believe, a different issue). Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Adrien by the way, if you post your comment as an answer I would be happy to accept it!

Comment: Sorry I said something dumb, you can't get rid of these vectors even in the Kauffmann bracket case (what you can gt rid of is the orientation of strands which is something else of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up: these tangent vectors are always present. In the literature on WZW one usually choose local formal coordinates at the marked point, ie an identification of the neighborhood of those with a chosen formal punctured disc, but this amount to essentially the same thing. The reason is compatibility with gluing: the moduli space of algebraic curves of genus $g$ with $n$ marked points with tangent vectors, is equivalent to the moduli space of genus $g$ surfaces with $n$ boundary components **together with a parametrization of the boundary** which is what you need to glue.

Btw, I wouldn't say BFS is a rigorous construction of the conformal blocks of the WZW model (this can already be made rigorous). Rather, my understanding is that it is a geometric construction of the modular functor associated with the modular tensor category of a quantum group at root of unity (hence, in particular, a direct geometric construction of that category as well). I think the point is to have a construction that looks like the construction of conformal blocks in WZW but on the quantum group side.

Once you know the modular tensor categories you get as the value of the circle for either of those constructions are the same, you can use e.g. Andersen-Ueno result (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611087) that a modular functor (in a somewhat restrictive sense) is determined by its genus 0 part to conclude these are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, as you alluded to, my main motivation for looking at BFS is that the local systems they obtain on $\mathcal{M}_{g,n}$ (plus tangent vectors at marked points plus determinant line bundle) seem to be motivic, i.e. come from algebraic geometry. I think this was already known in genus zero by work of Ramadas, Looijenga, and others.

Comment: Interesting, are you saying say the Tsuchiya-Ueno-Yamada construction of the conformal blocks "do not come from algebraic geometry" in that sense ?

Comment: That's right. To be more precise, for a local system to "come from AG" I mean it arises as singular cohomology of a family of varieties. Now as far as I understand, for a family of curves over a base $B$, the TUY construction works by taking coinvariants of a sheaf of affine Lie algebras over $B$ in some representation, and then defining some projective flat connection on it. Once you pass to the determinant line to get an honest flat connection, you get by Riemann-Hilbert a local system, and it's not clear that it should come from AG from the construction (at least to me).

Comment: I see, Interesting !